# Unity C# ограничение позиции драга

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно ограничить драг в unity? То есть мне нужно, чтобы за пределами определенной зоны драг прекращался. Драг начинает срабатывать в плейне в правой половину экрана. Как можно сделать так,чтобы за пределами этого плейна драг прекращался. [image: Драг начинает срабатывать в плейне в правой половину экрана. Как можно сделать так,чтобы за пределами этого плейна драг прекращался.]

```
 public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{ 
    Handle.transform.localPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint(eventData.pressPosition);
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Handle.localPosition += (Vector3)eventData.delta;


    if (eventData.dragging)
    {
        lookHor = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
        lookVer = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
    }
}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    lookHor = 0;
    lookVer = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используя вектора, ты можешь обращаться к его свойству `rndVector.magnitude`, которое возвращает длину твоего вектора. Делаешь условие на проверку длины

```
rndVector = (rndVector.magnitude > 1.0f) ? rndVector.normalised : rndVector;
```

[ссылка на документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html)

видео с таймингом
[ссылка на пример из видео](https://youtu.be/6J6-7MV6nrA?t=566)

Comment: понял. сейчас буду изменять и писать сам)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но удалось решить проблему самостоятельно другим способом (через координаты курсора) :)